# is there G-Code syntax for monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor, g-code

I'm trying to create a code editor via monaco loader which is going to do all of the appropriate formatting and highlighting for .g-code files. I understand that for this to work I need g-code as the language but g-code isn't on the list of options. Does anyone know where I can get g-code rules and how to implement them into my editor?

If anyone has already made something like that and is willing to share it then I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know where I can get gcode rules and how to implement them into my editor?

Read the code in the [vscode-gcode-syntax](https://github.com/appliedengdesign/vscode-gcode-syntax) repo very carefully as it is a great reference you can use to implement your own monarch language syntax.

#### Useful Resources to get started:

- [monaco-editor/monarch](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html)
  for interactive examples and documentation
- [monaco-languages](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-languages)

Comment: Got it, I have found a variety of g-code syntax rules at least for highlighting and now I am trying to implement them through monaco-editor new language registration tool - https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-custom-languages